# Plain Vanilla JavaScript - Reset appearance of all elements

Tags: javascript

I have a lot many elements in my HTML with different divs, objects having different sizes, classes, font-sizes.

Now I have a plain javascript function which reduces the divs on scroll like below:

```
    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 50
                || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
            document.getElementById("item1").style.padding = "5px 5px";
            document.getElementById("item-n-1").style.fontSize = "0.7rem";
            document.getElementById("item-n").style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
            document.getElementById("image1").width = "100";
            document.getElementById("image-n").height = "300";
        } else {
            //What should I do here so that all 
            //the elements reset back to their original appearance?
            //Looking for a smarter solution where I dont have to put my entire CSS here
        }
    }
```

**Question:** Is there a smarter way (vanilla plain javascript way) to reset all elements to their original appearance? The reason I am asking help is - I don't want make my js bulky by putting css parameters again in the js code. Any help in this regards will be much appreciated.

Comment: Refresh the page ..? Also, if you've made all the changes with inline styles, you could set the style properties to the empty string. That way the properties are removed, and the styles in the stylesheets are applied only.

Comment: You can dump all of the stylings into a javascript object and then recall them OR you can create all these rules as a CSS class and then add/remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add/remove a CSS class from a container, eg:

```
.toggle #item1 {
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
.toggle #item-n-1 {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
// etc
// this looks much easier syntactically if you use SASS
```

```
function scrollFunction() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('toggle', document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50);
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. it worked. Never thought in that direction. Help me understand please. So the idea is to add a toggle (say) class to all such elements and then onScroll use it. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: No, add a `toggle` class only to a single element, a container of all elements that will be changed. Eg, here, the class is being added only to the `document.body`, not to all elements.

Comment: Sweet.! Sorry I overlooked that. This is awesome. And thanks a lot for the explanation.